# JWT token in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, asp.net-mvc-4, single-sign-on, jwt

I am a new in Single Sign on Authentication

i have a MVC4 base website which is working on **JWT token authentication**. in between we have to implement one silverlight 5 application,

How can i read that JWT token in Silverlight application and how can i authenticate user in silverlight , also if user click on logoff from silverlight app or web app user must be signoff from both the application

it will be great help if you can provide an example.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

did you succeed on implementing JWT on a silverlight application?

**Update**

On my silverlight client code, I am adding the jwt token to the HTTP Header Authorization, for every request. In order to add the header, I created a behavior (AttachRequestInformationEndpointBehavior) that is responsible for that. The following code adds the behavior to the ExampleDomainContext:

```
    Partial Class ExampleDomainContext

      Private Sub OnCreated()
        Dim channelFactoryProperty As PropertyInfo = Me.DomainClient.GetType().GetProperty("ChannelFactory")

        If (channelFactoryProperty IsNot Nothing) Then
            Dim factory = TryCast(channelFactoryProperty.GetValue(Me.DomainClient, Nothing), channelFactory)

            If factory IsNot Nothing Then
                If Not factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Contains(GetType(Infrastructure.WebServices.AttachRequestInformationEndpointBehavior)) Then
                    factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(New Wintouch.Infrastructure.WebServices.AttachRequestInformationEndpointBehavior())
                End If
            End If
        End If
      End Sub

    End Class
```

If follows the code of the behavior:

```
Public Class AttachRequestInformationEndpointBehavior
    Implements IEndpointBehavior, IClientMessageInspector

    Public Sub AddBindingParameters(endpoint As ServiceEndpoint, bindingParameters As BindingParameterCollection) Implements IEndpointBehavior.AddBindingParameters
    End Sub

    Public Sub ApplyClientBehavior(endpoint As ServiceEndpoint, clientRuntime As System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime) Implements IEndpointBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior
        clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(Me)
    End Sub

    Public Sub ApplyDispatchBehavior(endpoint As ServiceEndpoint, endpointDispatcher As System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.EndpointDispatcher) Implements IEndpointBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior
    End Sub

    Public Sub Validate(endpoint As ServiceEndpoint) Implements IEndpointBehavior.Validate
    End Sub

    Public Sub AfterReceiveReply(ByRef reply As Message, correlationState As Object) Implements IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply
    End Sub

    Public Function BeforeSendRequest(ByRef request As Message, channel As IClientChannel) As Object Implements IClientMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest
        Dim header As HttpRequestMessageProperty

        If request.Properties.ContainsKey(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name) Then
            header = CType(request.Properties(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name), HttpRequestMessageProperty)
        Else
            header = New HttpRequestMessageProperty()
            request.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, header)
        End If

        header.Headers("Authorization") = "Bearer " + "the user token here..."

        Return Nothing
    End Function
```

On the server side, I just populate the HttpContext.Current.User and the Thread.CurrentPrincipal with information extracted from the token. For example:

In Global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState( Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // code to read the token
        var tokenHandler = new TokenHandler(); 

        // get the token from the http request header
        var authHeaders = Request.Headers.GetValues("Authorization");

        if (authHeaders == null || authHeaders.Length < 1) return;

        var authHeader = authHeaders[0].Split(' ');
        var scheme = authHeader[0];
        var tokenString = authHeader[1];

        if (scheme != "Bearer") return;

        // retrieves the principal from the token
        IPrincipal principal = tokenHandler.ReadPrincipal(tokenString);

        // set the relevant variables
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;

    }
```

Comment: No,Success is to far away to implement JWT token in Silverlight

Comment: Chirag, I actually did that. For each domain service, i created an interceptor that adds the jwt token to an http header. Then, at the server, I read the token and set the Principal. If you want to see my code, I can send you.

Comment: Hello  Cangosta , thanks for the post ,Please send the code to me on my email account chiragvm@outlook.com

Comment: Hi Chirag, did my post help you?